# MS Access SQL that shows courses NOT TAKEN by student before

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tried many ways, and i suspect NOT EXIST may help, but i am not sure how to implement the SQL statement. Someone help me please?

I have three tables in MS Access database.

```
Students (Student Name, Email)
Courses (Course Name, Fees)
Registration (Course Name, Student Name)
```

I want to now create a Query that can show me all classes that each student HAS NOT taken before. This will allow my Registration Manager to pursue them to perform more class registration.

How can I easy do this in MS ACCESS? The resulting query should be:

James|Advanced Flash
 
James|Advanced Editing
Adrian|Basic Editing
Adrian|Basic Flash
Adrian|Advanced Flash
Adrian|Advanced Editing

(James have taken all 'Basic' classes where else Adrian has not taken 'Basic' and 'Advanced' classes)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to create all combines of students and courses.  Then do a `left join` to `Registrations`.  Anything that *does not* match is a course not taken.

Access syntax is a bit different from other databases.  I think the following is the Access syntax for this type of query:

```
select s.studentName, c.CourseName
from ((select studentName
       from students
      ) s,
      (select CourseName
       from courses
      ) c
     ) left join
     Registration r
     on r.StudentName = s.StudentName and
        r.CourseName = s.CourseName
where r.StudentName is NULL;
```

EDIT:

I think the parens might have to be ordered correctly for Access to understand the joins.  In any case, the following should work.  The `driver` subquery gets all combinations of students and courses, which is then used for the `left join`:

```
select driver.StudentName, driver.CourseName
from (select distinct StudentName, CourseName
      from students, courses
     ) driver left join
     Registration r
     on r.StudentName = driver.StudentName and
        r.CourseName = driver.CourseName
where r.StudentName is NULL;
```

Comment: thaks for the answer, Gordon, but strangely, i get a Syntax Error on Left Join. Does Access support LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Super! we are close, Gordon. However, now I get everything. Meaning, i get all the courses they have taken and also all the courses that they have not taken too. I am lost in fixing it. Mind sharing how i can fix this? Thanks, Gordon :)

Comment: Also, Gordon, is there anyway that I can do this without using 'Driver' as my Development environments would not recognise it in the sql statement. Any statements that has Driver in it, the IDE would choose not to include them in my list of queries stored in Access. :(

Comment: I have now managed to make it work in the IDE, it can detect Driver SQL statements, HOWEVER the query still show EVERY courses against the students, taken OR otherwise and i have been trying to do this for sometime now,... any idea how to not include those courses already taken, Gordon? My sincerest thansk in advance, G :)

Comment: @user2418485 . . . Are you sure you have the `where` clause?  That should be filtering out the courses for each student where there is a registration.

Comment: Ah ha! Good news, Gordon! Found one the problem was that some of the courses was not entered correctly! AND THUS, YES,.. YOUR LOVELY SQL STATEMENT WORKS LIKE CHARM! Thank you sir,.. and if i ever in New York, you are one person i am surely to buy a lunch! Thank you very much for your kind help, sir :)