# MS Access SQL Employee Training Database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database which is used to keep track of employee training.

The database has three tables:

```
tblEmployees(EmployeeID, Name, Function) 
tblTraining_Courses(CourseID, Title, Desc, Function)
tblTraining_Records(EmployeeID, CourseID, Date, Status)
```

EmployeeID is their personnel number
Name is the Employee's name
Function is the product line the employee supports - Electric, Lighting or Both (Multivalue Lookup)
CourseID is the courses's ID number
Status is whether the course has been completed

I am trying to query the "tblTraining_Records" table to see which employees have not completed a training course.

I followed another example posted here and it works really well: [Stackoverflow: MS Access SQL Course not Taken Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683304/ms-access-sql-that-shows-courses-not-taken-by-student-before)

However, I also want to filter that query based on whether the employees function matches the courses function. The function is a multivalue lookup field with three possible choices Electrical, Lighting or Both. Courses can also be for just Electrical, Lighting or Both.

Here is the SQL I have for my query.

```
SELECT nested.EmployeeID, nested.Course_ID
FROM (SELECT distinct EmployeeID, Course_ID FROM tblEmployees, tblTraining_Courses) nested 
LEFT JOIN tblTraining_Records r ON r.EmployeeID = nested.EmployeeID AND r.Course_ID = nested.Course_ID
WHERE r.Employee is NULL;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Join courses with with nested table and then add a new condition in where clause as following:

```
SELECT nested.EmployeeID, nested.Course_ID
FROM (SELECT distinct EmployeeID, Course_ID FROM tblEmployees, tblTraining_Courses) nested 
LEFT JOIN tblTraining_Records r ON r.EmployeeID = nested.EmployeeID AND r.Course_ID = nested.Course_ID
inner join   tblTraining_Courses tc on  nested.course_ID=tc.CourseID
WHERE r.Employee is NULL and tc.Title IN ('Electrical', 'Lighting');
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add this approach:  (lets call this Query1)
When you join all 3 tables, and have all the fields in the query - you'll have 2 fields named Function.  This isn't allowed so let's alias that to eFunction for employee and cFunction for course.

Then create a calculated field: 
Completed: iif(cFunction = eFunction, "Yes", Null)

then you can filter Query1 on Yes